# Postgres/psycopg2 "executue_values": Which argument was not converted during string formatting?

Tags: python, postgresql, debugging, psycopg2, sqldatatypes

I am using `execute_values` to insert a list of lists of values into a postgres database using psycopg2. Sometimes I get "not all arguments converted during string formatting", indicating that one of the values in one of the lists is not the expected data type (and also not NoneType). When it is a long list, it can be a pain to figure out which value in which list was causing the problem.

1. Is there a way to get postgres/psycopg2 to tell me the specific 'argument which could not be converted'?
2. If not, what is the most efficient way to look through the list of lists and find any incongruent data types per place in the list, excluding NoneTypes (which obviously are not equal to a value but also are not the cause of the error)?

Please note that I am not asking for help with the specific set of values I am executing it, but trying to find a general method to more quickly inspect the problem query so I can debug it.

Comment: In my experience this is always because one of the tuples after the first tuple is longer than the first tuple is.  I've never seen it be due to some typing issue.  Although I suppose there are many things I haven't seen before.

Comment: I think that without seeing a specific example that resulted in this behavior we'll have a hard time providing useful feedback. In general, this error message *is* how you diagnose and debug the problem; the solution is usually obvious (and is typically a missing parameter).

Comment: It could be that too. In any case, if I could see the problem expression, I could see what is wrong with it.

Comment: I don't see why the specific example is relevant. If I do execute_values on a list of lists and get an error, I want to know which sublist caused the error. I could check the length of all the sublists in advance to make sure they are equal, but I'd rather just have something in my code to print the values that could not be executed.

Comment: Well, you could always go edit the psycopg2/extras.py file to implement what you want.  This is not really a forum for feature requests.

Comment: This due to not enough placeholders for the values supplied. A possible quick and dirty method `try: cur.execute_values(<list_of_lists> except TypeError as err: for l in list_of lists: if len(l) > placeholder_ct: print(l) ` **Not tested**.